# Protect MediaPlayer function in Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player

How to protect MediaPlayer function from error I mean when I click a button to play sound (multiple times) after about 5th click application forces close. I have tried to do something like counter and after 2nd click it was stopping, preparing and releasing MP but it's not working

Comment: If you show your code, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i defined `MediaPlayer` and `counter` static like as follow:

```
public class Global {
    public static int counter = 0;

    public static MediaPlayer MP;
}
```

And use them where i need (e.g in an `OnClickListener`) as follow:

```
Global.counter ++;
if (Global.counter >= 2) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do another thing
}
```